# General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value while uploading image

Tags: 7

I am using Drupal 7 and I got the following error while uploading an image.

**PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: ''** for column 'field_third_section_image_width' at row 1:

```
INSERT INTO {field_data_field_third_section_image} (entity_type, entity_id, revision_id, bundle, delta, language, field_third_section_image_fid, field_third_section_image_alt, field_third_section_image_title, field_third_section_image_width, 
field_third_section_image_height) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4,
 :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7,
 :db_insert_placeholder_8, :db_insert_placeholder_9, :db_insert_placeholder_10);
     Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => node 
    [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 107 
    [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => 107 
    [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => page 
    [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 0 
    [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => und 
    [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => 12464 
    [:db_insert_placeholder_7] => 
    [:db_insert_placeholder_8] => 
    [:db_insert_placeholder_9] => 
    [:db_insert_placeholder_10] => ) 
    
    in field_sql_storage_field_storage_write() (line 514 of /mysite/modules/field/modules/field_sql_storage/field_sql_storage.module).
```

Its also give some image related error on recent logs

**Unable to generate the derived image located at public://styles/thumbnail/public/imac1.png.**

Whenever I trying to upload the image and save the node then it gives the following error.
I have already given the writable permission to files directory and tmp directory.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any values for these columns in the SQL query: field_third_section_image_alt, field_third_section_image_title, field_third_section_image_width,
field_third_section_image_height

So there must have something for these fields in order for the query to work. Have a look at the code and see why they are not set.